# React native -offline video encryption+decryption

Tags: react-native, encryption, video-streaming

I am working on e-learing application and i have a situation to save videos offline. Because of this is a learning application i have to secure the video with encryption. how can i achieve this

Comment: hi @pranav malayil have you created this functionality?

Comment: yes i have implemented it

Comment: Can you provide me some detail how have you did it? @pranav malayil